# How to unfocus (blur) Python-gi GTK+3 window on Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, x11, gtk3

**What I want to do and why**

I want my window to unfocus, so the previous focused window is selected.

Why? I want to interact with the previously selected window (from other programs). My current plan is: unfocus my window, use `libxdo` to simulate keystrokes, then focus my window again.

My window can be set on top to help avoid flicking. Should be good enough. Looks simple to me. But I can't get it to work.

**What I've tried so far**

Hiding the window with `Gtk.Widget.hide()` and then showing it again: The window flickers too much and it's slightly moved some pixels to the top  (because of window manager stubbornness, I suppose).

**Sample test code**

Current code calls `Gtk.Window.set_focus(None)` that does not work. I need to replace that line with something else that makes what I want it to do.

`losefocus.py`:

```
import signal
from gi import require_version
require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk, GObject

class LoseFocusHandler:
  def onClick(self, window):
    print "Losing focus yet?"
    window1 = builder.get_object("window1")
    window1.set_focus(None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  GObject.threads_init()

  builder = Gtk.Builder()
  builder.add_from_file("losefocus.glade")
  builder.connect_signals(LoseFocusHandler())
  window1 = builder.get_object("window1")
  window1.show_all()

  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
  Gtk.main()
```

`losefocus.glade`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center-always</property>
    <property name="gravity">center</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Lose Focus!</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
        <property name="relief">half</property>
        <signal name="clicked" handler="onClick" swapped="no"/>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to record which window had focus before, both when creating the window and then on each `focus-in-event`, and explicitly focus that window instead of trying to unfocus the active one:

```
import signal
from gi import require_version
require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gdk, Gtk, GObject

class LoseFocusHandler:
  def onClick(self, window):
    print "Losing focus yet?"
    old_window[0].focus(0)

def focus_handler(gdk_window, event):
    # At this point, our window does not have focus yet, but is
    # about to. This hence works:
    old_window[0] = gdk_window.get_screen().get_active_window()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  GObject.threads_init()

  old_window = [ Gdk.Screen.get_default().get_active_window() ]

  builder = Gtk.Builder()
  builder.add_from_file("losefocus.glade")
  builder.connect_signals(LoseFocusHandler())
  window1 = builder.get_object("window1")
  window1.connect("focus-in-event", focus_handler)
  window1.show_all()

  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
  Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Very clever! Thanks for the tip. However, this doesn't work properly, at least with Unity 7. The previous window is highlighted in the taskbar but it's not focused at all.

Comment: Unity has a *focus stealing prevention* feature, which it inherited from [compiz](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/369954/comments/2), designed to prevent programs from changing focus but highlighting programs in the taskbar instead. A GDKWindow's `focus()` method [invokes the appropriate Xlib command](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gdk/x11/gdkwindow-x11.c#L2250), and it works fine in Cinnamon. I found pages that claim that you can adjust the setting using CCSM → General Options → Focus & Raise Behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need something that works out of the box on Ubuntu.
I want to send keystrokes to the other window. Since I know thanks to you how to get the other window ID, I can now use xdo to get the focus on that window, type and then restore the focus.
I posted a working example here: http://pastebin.com/0BsKYZtP
I tried using a xdo feature to type to a certain window using the window ID, but it seems `XSendEvent` won't work either. So I separately activate the window, then type, and then restore the focus. That way I'm only relying on `Xtest` that seems to work flawlessly.

Comment: I should definitely try to use the python xdo module in the Ubuntu package python-xdo, but it seems to be dead and undocumented. Calling `xdotool` isn't so bad, or is it?

Comment: Mind that if you send a keyboard event directly, you have to send it to the Xid of the input widget, not to the window that owns it. I'd personally use XLib for this, but `xdotool` will do fine, sure. (I [use a script to paste passwords into the active window](https://github.com/phillipberndt/scripts/blob/master/passwrd/passwrd.py), you might be able to reuse parts of it.)

Comment: So the widgets also have xids? Wow, I'm so lost with this haha. Thanks for the tip, I think I'll stick with this for now. I'll keep that link for future reference, thanks again :)!