# How to make an overlay which capture no events

Tags: linux, gtk, x11, cairo

I would like to draw some sort of window on top of all the other windows. For example, to display some debugging infos (like conky) or things like a timer.

The main thing is that I would like to able to continue using the other windows while using it (the events go through transparently).

I've tried doing it with `pygtk`, `pyqt` and others but can't find a way to make it a real overlay with no event capture.

Is there some low-level x11 solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Composite-extension-approach will not work when a compositing manager is running (and thus Composite's overlay window is already used).

Since you explicitly mention "no event capture":

The [SHAPE extension](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xextproto/shape.html) allows to set some different shapes for a window. Version 1.1 of this extension added the "input" shape. Just setting this to an empty region should pretty much do what you want.

Some concrete example of exactly what I think you ask for can be found in Conky's source code: http://sources.debian.net/src/conky/1.10.3-1/src/x11.cc/?hl=769#L764-L781

Edit: Since you said that you didn't find anything in Gtk (well, PyGtk), here is the function that you need in Gtk: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-input-shape-combine-region

Comment: I've tried this approach too but didn't think it would let me setup a pass-through window because the [QT example for that](https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/blob/master/examples/widgets/shapedclock.py) won't. But, I'm gonna try the GTK one and report back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think this is the right way to go, my version is crashing (segfault under python 3, assertion error under python 2) but here it is for history: https://gist.github.com/mdamien/a1f864ab3ef3c63f63e136123cc43c56

Comment: found this comment, very related to this problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pygobject/+bug/1028115/comments/8

Answer (score 1):

You might need [Composite extension](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/compositeproto/compositeproto.txt) + GetOverlayWindow request:

> Version 0.3 of the protocol adds the Composite Overlay Window, which
>   provides compositing managers with a surface on which to draw without
>   interference. This window is always above normal windows and is always
>   below the screen saver window. It is an InputOutput window whose width
>   and height are the screen dimensions. Its visual is the root visual
>   and its border width is zero.  Attempts to redirect it using the
>   composite extension are ignored.  This window does not appear in the
>   reply of the QueryTree request. It is also an override redirect
>   window. These last two features make it invisible to window managers
>   and other X11 clients. The only way to access the XID of this window
>   is via the CompositeGetOverlayWindow request. Initially, the Composite
>   Overlay Window is unmapped.
>
> CompositeGetOverlayWindow returns the XID of the Composite Overlay
>   Window. If the window has not yet been mapped, it is mapped by this
>   request. When all clients who have called this request have terminated
>   their X11 connections the window is unmapped.
>
> Composite managers may render directly to the Composite Overlay
>   Window, or they may reparent other windows to be children of this
>   window and render to these. Multiple clients may render to the
>   Composite Overlay Window, create child windows of it, reshape it, and
>   redefine its input region, but the specific arbitration rules followed
>   by these clients is not defined by this specification; these policies
>   should be defined by the clients themselves.

C api : [XCompositeGetOverlayWindow](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xcompositegetoverlaywindow)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's already pretty much sufficient to what I need. But, just in case, any idea where I could find an example of an app using it ? Even better, a small snippet ?

Comment: The Debian Code Search is usually quite useful for that.

Answer (score 1):

PyGTK Solution:

I think the composite and shapes X extensions are sufficiently ubiquitous and shall assume here that they are active on your system. Here's PyGtk code for this:

```
# avoid title bar and standard window minimize, maximize, close buttons
win.set_decorated(False)

# make the window stick above all others (super button will still override it in the z-order, which is fine)
win.set_keep_above(True)

# make events pass through
region = cairo.Region(cairo.RectangleInt(0, 0, 0, 0))
my_window.input_shape_combine_region(region)

win.show_all()

# set the entire window to be semi-transparent, if we like
win.set_opacity(0.2)
```

Basically what this does is tell Gtk that other than pixel (0,0) the entire window `my_window` should not be considered part of itself in terms of event propagation. That in turn, according to my current understanding means that when the pointer moves and clicks, the events go to the underlying window under the pointer position, as if `my_window` was not there.

Caveat:

This does allow your overlay window being the focus window (due to user-solicited window switching or just because it pops up and gets the focus when your application starts). Which means that for example, keyboard events will still undesirably go to it up until the user has clicked through it to make it lose focus in favor of whatever window is under the cursor. I would likely use the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36137157/1509695) to iron out this aspect.

If there's a different and proper approach for making a portion of the screen "display stuff but not receive events", without building an oddball window like above over it, I'm happy to learn about it.

I assume that one's particular desktop environment (gnome, unity, etc. on linux) may interfere with this solution depending on version and configuration, on some occasions.